# TFS Build Definition with multiple builds of the same project and app.config changes in between

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

I am working on a build definition on the **TFS**. The current way to handle the problem with this project is to trigger a build, take the deployed setup files, then change a setting in the **app.config** (multiple **regions** for the product to be used, it's just one value that changes), and **manually** trigger another build. This is repeated for each region.
I am trying to automate this process, and my approach has been to use a **Powershell** inline script build step to change the value in the app.config and repeat the "**Build Solution**" and "**Copy Publish Artifact**" build steps. The error I have been getting is:

*Artifact installer already exists for build X*.

Is there a better approach to this? I'm not too familiar with the possibilities of TFS Build definitions.

**Edit:**

The build runs now, the issue is that the Powershell script doesn't seem to take effect, but I have tested it somewhere else where it edit the file. Checking the drop location, there are multiple setup files that are **identical**. Does it need to be checked out and checked in again or something?

This is the script:

```
(get-content $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Source\projectname\app.config) |

Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "$ServerRegionCE","$ServerRegionUK"}  |

set-content $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\Source\projectname\app.config
```

Comment: A better approach is to look at what devops practicies could offer you. That means: 1. build a package with useless values in your app.config file. 2. Make the deployment with a release tool like "OctopusDeploy" that will substitute the values in the app.config depending on where you want to deploy.

Comment: I realize that there are extensions, such as Octopus, that could very much work for this. I am trying to find a simple solution without using additional TFS extensions, because I can't add them without consulting an admin. 
I thought it would be easier to just use a powershell script since the change is very minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update with solution:**
I managed to do what I wanted by throwing that powershell script away. The way Andy Li-MSFT posted it it should work, but I instead added a "Copy Files" Build step that runs right before the solution is built. I created folders in the source code, each server region specific folder containing the corresponding app.config to be copied into the project source before the project is built and deployed.

It looks like this:
[image]

The UnitedKingdom_Config folder, in this case, only has the *app.config*, if there are other files you would obviously need to specify the file in the **Contents** field.

Answer (score 1):

> the issue is that the Powershell script doesn't seem to take effect

The root cause is that the syntax of the referenced variable is incorrect.

In PowerShell script you need to use the variable `$env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY` instead of `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`

It also applies for the custom defined variables. So if you defined the variable `$ServerRegionCE` and `$ServerRegionUK` in build process, then you can use them like below format:

`$env:ServerRegionCE` and `$env:ServerRegionUK`

See [Working with variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/process/variables?view=vsts&tabs=designer%2Cbatch#working-with-variables) for details.

So, just try below script:

```
(get-content $env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\Source\projectname\app.config) |

Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "$env:ServerRegionCE","$env:ServerRegionUK"}  |

set-content $env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\Source\projectname\app.config
```

Comment: I see, I stumbled upon that syntax, but I could have sworn that it worked with my syntax in a test project. Anyway, I got it working now using the "Copy Files" build step, so that I copy the needed app.config file before each Build. Would you say the powershell variant is a better solution?

Comment: @tweedledum11 No, just troubleshoot the issue you mentioned in your question. The solutions modify the file or copy files to source directory to replace the previous one have the same effect.  "Copy Files" is more easier.. Well, you could post your solution as an answer, then accept it. This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Comment: I will update my question sometime today and provide my solution next to your updated script, thanks for the help anyway! 
Would the question of renaming the deployed setup file within this tfs build definition require an entirely new question?

Comment: @tweedledum11 Yeah, any new topics you'd better create a new thread to track the new question.